# seekg after reading to the end of the file

Tags: c++, ifstream, seekg

I'm trying to use the code below on the ifstream twice - before I read anything from the file, and after I read to the end of it (using `readline()`).

```
m_hexFile->m_ifsteam->seekg(0, m_hexFile->m_ifsteam->ios_base::end);
test1 = m_hexFile->m_ifsteam->tellg();
m_hexFile->m_ifsteam->clear();
m_hexFile->m_ifsteam->seekg(m_hexFile->m_startPosition);
test1 = m_hexFile->m_ifsteam->tellg();
```

(`m_startPosition`  is some poisition in the middle of the file. It is not important for this issue.)

On the first run, the code works as expected. Then when I run it the second time, the value of the variable `test1` is -1, even after using `clear()`.

I looked through the similar questions, and all of the solutions said to use function `clear()` (which I already do).

Comment: Half of the code uses `m_hexFile->getFileRef()` and half uses `m_hexFile->m_ifsteam`. Are they interchangable? Can't tell since that code is missing. Consider a [mcve].

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, they are interchangable.

Comment: Prove it with a [mcve].

Comment: @RetiredNinja In the middle of making minimal example, I noticed the bug in my code. I was closing the stream somewhere else. Using seekg() on closed streams ofcourse always returns -1. So I guess thank you for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to check elsewhere. I had closed the stream somewhere else in the program. Using the code above on a closed stream ofcourse wont work.